# Application to open default browser on scanning of QR code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, qr-code, barcode

We have a user scanning a QR code which we store a URL. USB QR code scanners are like keyboards in they type in whatever is stored in the QR code.

We need to find something that will open a browser when a scan is made so that the URL in the QR code, can be typed into the browser URL bar.

Any ideas?